# hyphen in sql query is causing the issue

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to query from database asking for data with this filter. i want that the word which is after not like not to exist in my result query. but my result is still having the that word.

```
select * from table where titel not like '%word-word%'
```

but i am still getting the query where the title has the word `'word-word'`.

do i have to escape the query for `'-'`

is there any difference between `like` and `not like` in this sense ?

Comment: Works for me, too. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/526a8/1

Comment: www.top-jobs-europe.de this is word i want to exclude. is ``.`` playing role here ?

Comment: :( it is working in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong with your query. check whether your table contains 'word-word'.

try this

```
select * from table where title not like '%word-word%'
```

Comment: sorry guys, it was working, i had problem somewhere else :(, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I used following query and its working fine for me

```
select * from table1 where titel 
not like '%word-word%'
```

check for 'word-word' data in your table. And make sure it does not contain any unwanted spaces

Comment: no, this is the word actually: ``www.top-jobs-europe.de`` i am filtering against ``top-jobs`` but in the result it is still ``www.top-jobs-europe.de`` there

Answer (score 1):

Here firstly

1)"Like" will checks for the word or character in db and if found than displays in result.

2)"Not Like" will also do same but here it will not displaying the result.It will be excluded.

Comment: yeah i want to the second one, i know this